# SwiftUI - Dynamically refresh UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to implement a colour theme selector in my app. The last hurdle I am trying to overcome is dynamically changing the colour of my UINavigationBar. At present, my function to change the colour does work, but it only takes effect when the app has been relaunched from a closed state.

My root view controller sets the initial state of UINavigationBar like so:

```
struct MyRootView: View {

            init() {
                UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = getPreferredThemeColour() 
                UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            }

var body: some View {
...
```

getPreferredThemeColour() simply returns the desired UIColour from UserDefaults

My theme selector has buttons that change the colour attributes like so:

```
 Button(action: {
 UserDefaults.standard.set(UIColor.blue, forKey: "theme")
 UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue }) {
```

I can't seem to find any way to refresh UINavigationBar "on the fly" to reflect the changes made. The app always needs to be relaunched.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Appearance applied to the instances created *after* appearance itself. So the solution is to recreate `NavigationView` after appearance changed.

Here is a worked demo of approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoNavigationBarColor: View {
    @State private var force = UUID()

    init() {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView(){
                List(1 ... 20, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                        Text("Details \(item)")
                    ) {
                        Text("Row \(item)")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)

            }.id(force)  // recreate NavigationView

            Button("Be Green") {
                UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
                self.force = UUID() // << here !!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This works fine in a single view, however I am trying to initialise the UINavigation attributes in my root view, then change it in one of my sub views responsible for themes. Would there be a way to hit self.force = UUID() from a different view?

Comment: @d5automations Did you end up finding your solution for triggering the self.force in seperate sub views? If so, would you mind sharing or linking to the solution that worked for you?

Comment: @956MB you may use EnvironmentObject or Binding to trigger self.force. But if you recreate the NavigationView in the subviews, all but rootView in NavigationView  will be removed.

Comment: Should this work with textAttributes?  I tried and couldn't get it to work.